# Mismatch of displaying value and value getted programmatically in .net DateTimePicker control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a problem using .net built in DateTimePicker control - sometimes trying to programmatically  get a `Value` property from control I'm getting not the same value that currently displayed.

For example - code line:

```
DateTime supposed_date = dtp_StartDate.Value;
```

despite that displayed in `dtp_StartDate` value says it set to `"03.03.2013 12:03:05"` I get `supposed_date.Value == "03.03.2013 11:33:07"`

This problem is inconsistent so I can't understand what's I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Smells like `Culture` stuff?

Comment: If you mean specifying CultureInfo, I don't really understand how it can affect displaying value. It seems just like displayed value and real stored value are different properties, although they are not.

Comment: I had an idea, that value of DateTimePicker may be corrupted when I saving it in a new DateTime object, but I'm still not sure why and how I can fix it.

Comment: Being off by an hour using indicates a problem with daylight savings time.  Or getting UTC vs local time mixed up and living in mainland Europe.  DateTimePicker is not well known for problems like that, best to look for a bug in handling dates in your code.

Comment: I gave a bad example in my question - it's not literally an 1 hour shift of time value, it may be several minutes, or any other time value - it's seems more like that DateTime value that control had when it was initialized doesn't change when I'm changing value displayed in control.

Comment: I think `DateTimePicker` is usually used for holding and displaying `Date` only not `time`. How do you set the value for your `DateTimePicker`? I've tested to set a fixed DateTime value to its `Value` and try getting its `Value` and it showed the `Value` exactly what it displayed.

Comment: Usually Time component of my DateTimePicker is being changed by entering hours/minutes/seconds values from a keyboard. When value is changed programmatically I don't have problems either, - as I mentioned I even can't catch described bug by debugging, but It's often raising in a built application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally find the source of the problem:
In one method of parent form, containing the parent control to the DateTimePicker control, I had a code part that changes custom format mask for the date-time input for DateTimePicker. And although the was no exception raised after format was changed and no indication of code execution problem whatsoever after changing custom format mask for input values - any user edit of DateTimePicker doesn't affect actual Value property of control - just displaying value.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mikhail Tregubov  try this

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime SomeDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime();
        }
```

it will set to the exact value

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime Suposed_Date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime();
        }
```

this is for the button click

Comment: Unfortunately I need to get the value by pressing a button, - I'm currently don't have a watcher for ValueChanged. May be restoring a copy of DateTimePicker value every time it changes may solve the problem (at least I may be sure that the Value actually changes), but it doesn't seem like a good solution

Comment: then my edit should solve your problem,just change my datetimepicker1 to your dtp_StartDate

Comment: as I've described in my comments to another answer - I don't think it's the format of Value property that what's the problem - it's seems more like it's just when I'm setting time and date in control it doesn't properly work and Value property of control doesn't changes

Comment: ok,sorry mikhail,just i tried with setting a value with control(datetimepicker),and the value was also coming like yours,with this i got it to get the right hour

Comment: I'll try your solution, but as I mentioned - the problem is inconsistent - I can't catch it while debugging - it accidently pops up in a built application

Comment: hi just 1 more final option(very remote),because i cant extend much more the comments.....try to see if when you validate the value the datetimepicker loses focus,if he does not it will not validate new data....best wishes mikhail